# Word order and focus ("this finding needs to be cautiously interpreted")

Tags: word-order, emphasis

> Although this finding needs to be cautiously interpreted, /.../

How does this sound to a native speaker? Would it make any difference if we change it to:

> Although this finding needs to be interpreted cautiously, /.../

... or ...

> Although this finding needs to be interpreted with caution, /.../

My understanding would be that in the first version, one is emphasizing the need to interpret this finding (albeit with caution), whereas in the 2nd and 3rd versions, the emphasis is on being cautious (whereas interpreting the finding is taken for granted). Does it work like that in English?

Comment: It's stretching a point to suggest a real "difference" in meaning with your specific example, because both versions refer to ***interpretation***, and there's no real scope for alluding to the possibility that the findings might not be "interpreted" ***at all***...

Comment: ...But consider *To be successful, this project needs [to be **funded generously / generously funded***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+funded+generously%2Cbe+generously+funded&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20funded%20generously%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20generously%20funded%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbe%20funded%20generously%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20generously%20funded%3B%2Cc0) Arguably the ***generously funded*** more explicitly acknowledges the possibility that *it might not be funded at all* (but if it *is*, it must be generously).

Comment: Thanks! In the context where this sentence comes from, it is fine to say that a finding should not be interpreted at all. (Which is equivalent to saying that the finding is not a "thing" - e.g., it might be unreliable or there might be too many confounding factors.)

Comment: I think what you mean is when someone says anything like *this information needs to be "treated carefully"*, what they really mean is ***they don't accept it, and would like it to be ignored by everyone***. The actual word "interpret" in such contexts is usually just a "weasel word" from a speaker who doesn't want to come straight out and say *these findings **are misleading, and should be ignored***.

Comment: In statistical analyses, there are often results that should not be interpreted "as such". For example, an average difference between men and women (say, in height) should not be interpreted (but is there) if the sample is not representative (men come from a local basketball club and women from a crochet club) or too small to make reliable conclusions. But I agree that it is (almost?) the same as to say that the findings should be ignored.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, I would not distinguish between these (except that the first is somewhat awkward, and the third most natural). But if I _had_ to assign distinct meanings, I would do it the same way you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between any of those clauses. In each case, what is being mandated is cautious interpretation.

Personally, I find “to be cautiously interpreted” slightly awkward and prefer “to be interpreted cautiously” or “to be interpreted with caution,” but not due to any difference in meaning.

Comment: I am accepting the answer that came first but the usage chart from the other answer (by FumbleFingers) is also instructive. Thank you both!

Comment: Indeed. I didn't include it, because ***need to be interpreted with caution*** is more words than can appear in a single Googe Books search string. But actually, the results are just as meaningful without that initial ***need***, so here's the "full" usage chart...

Comment: [...showing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+be+cautiously+interpreted%2Cto+be+interpreted+cautiously%2Cto+be+interpreted+with+caution&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20cautiously%20interpreted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20interpreted%20cautiously%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20interpreted%20with%20caution%3B%2Cc0) that ***to be interpreted with caution*** is far more common anyway. There's no real equivalent alternative with my ***done quickly*** example, though, which may be significant.

Comment: A usage chart is of no value if different word orders have different meanings, **which is the topic of your question.** It turns out that “he hit her” is more common than “she hit him,” but that does not mean that “he hit her” is a valid way to describe an assault on a man by a woman. I suspect thar FF went to ngram because he did not take seriously the idea that the difference in word order being discussed could possibly represent a semantic difference. Ngram is useful in determining what published writers view as more idiomatic expressions of the same thought.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting [this usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=needs%20to%20be%20cautiously%20interpreted%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20interpreted%20cautiously&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20cautiously%20interpreted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20interpreted%20cautiously%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20cautiously%20interpreted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20interpreted%20cautiously%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

I must say I'm surprised the ***cautiously interpreted*** version appears as often as it does - I personally find it rather peculiar. At least I'm reassured to see that my fellow Anglophones are more solidly in agreement with [this much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=needs%20to%20be%20quickly%20done%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20done%20quickly&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20done%20quickly%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20done%20quickly%3B%2Cc0) *verb + adverb* construction *(**done quickly / quickly done**)*...

[image]

---

I think it's ridiculous to suggest that *either* of these examples could have a different meaning depending on whether the adverb comes before or after the verb.

---

TLDR: Both versions are syntactically valid and semantically equivalent - but one is "more idiomatic" (to at least *some* people! :)